# How can I get rid of a Man in the Middle (MitM) hacker from stealing web form data?

Tags: forms, security, business-catalyst, man-in-the-middle

I have a web form created in the Adobe Business Catalyst CRM and someone has placed a Man in the Middle (MitM) hack on our site or wherever and is intercepting the web form then contacting the user who submitted the form and offering them their products using the same name as my website.

So this is a two-part question. How do I get rid of and prevent this from happening again and is there any legal action I can take against the MitM hackers?

Comment: A [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) is abbreviated MitM. Wikipedia also notes MITM, MIM, MiM, and MITMA as valid.  I've never heard of MIMA used for this. In fact, *this question* is the top hit for [_"MIMA" man-in-the-middle_](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22MIMA%22+man-in-the-middle) on DuckDuckGo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Business Catalyst (BC) is very secure so I am not convinced there is a hack on your site. You should do the following:

1. Contact BC and let them know about this.
2. Check your site for any code you did not create or insert into your site.
3. Recreate the web form and insert it into your site.
4. Change passwords on your BC site.
5. Change the workflows for your site.
6. Change your email password.
7. Switch the forms to use the BC secure domain. (IE: `https://example.worldsecuresystems.com`)

Since you cannot run server side code on BC then doing the above steps should solve the issue.

Contact a lawyer for information on legal action against MIMA hackers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can use SSL on you website.

Second you can encrypt you data use  !!!

Comment: You can't install your own SSL certificate on BC websites. Every site comes with its own secure URL: yoursite.worldsecuresystems.com